# How to get HBox if the button in the HBox was clicked on in JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx, hbox

I am trying to figure out how to get the `HBox` object if the `Button` sitting in the `HBox` was clicked on, in JavaFX.

```java
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          Button btn = (Button)event.getSource();
          //get the the Hbox object that this button in is
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `btn.getParent()`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getParent--